# mac os high sierra - can't find user folder

Tags: macos

I want to show hidden folder /Users/ but i don't have box 'show library' in view options.

I followed this link:
https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6530671

and I've tried this:

```
chflags nohidden ~/Library
```

and still nothing... I don't see it in finder

Anyone knows how i can show users folder ? I'm running Mac OS High Sierra 
10.13.6

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

press  `Command + Shift + .`  in the home directory

or in terminal execute following command and then restart Finder:

```
defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles YES
```

Comment: how can I find home directory ? New window in finder ?

Comment: open terminal and execute 'cd ~'. this will redirect you into home directory, then execute ' open .  '. this will open home directory in Finder

Answer (score 0):

Type `Command + Shift + h`

This will take you right to the home folder. `(i.e /Users/foo/)` in the finder window.

Hope this helps !!